# MySQL Replace single backslash

Tags: mysql

Trying to replace a single backslash in a large db. Was going to run an Update Replace query on one column, but I can't figure out how to replace a single backslash. There was some poor updates done and these slashes need to be changed to another character, they are not escaping anything and do not perform any relevant function.

```
SELECT
REPLACE (
    "Some\s string\s with slashe\s",
    '\\',
    '  something  '
)
```

When I run this, the output is: "Somes strings with slashes"

Is there any way to do a true replace on a single slash? No matter what I put in the replace parameter, it just eliminates the single backslash, but doesn't actually replace it. Not sure if this is a bug or I'm just missing something.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
REPLACE (
    "Some\s string\s with slashe\s",
    '\',
    '  something  '
)
```

and I get:

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\')' at line 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The parameters of replace() don't need escaping:

select replace('A\B\C', '\', '\');

output:

```
A\\\\B\\C
```

So this will work:

```
select Name from T where Name = replace('A\\B\C', '\', '\\');
```

AS seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059450/mysql-replace-backslash-in-strings)

Comment: I get "[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\')' at line 1"

Answer (score 4):

`REPLACE( )` doesn't need to be escaped

```
select replace("Some\s string\s with slashe\s", '\\', '  something  ');
```

**UPDATE 1**

I think you want to permanently replace it. Right? Use `UPDATE` not `SELECT`

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    columnName = replace(columnName, '\\', '#');
```

Comment: As commented above, I get "[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\')' at line 1".

Comment: @Jestep I just updated the answer. Do you want to permanently replace the column? or you want only to project it?

Comment: I see now. Just ran a test on a few columns. The Update works, but if I simply try to run a select it shows the incorrect output. I was using the select on a static string just to verify the output would be correct.

Comment: It's because `SELECT` and `UPDATE` are two different things. Anything you do with `SELECT` doesn't change anything on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> SELECT REPLACE ("Some\s string\s with slashe\s",'\"','' )