# Replace strings with escape charectors

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL field which contains a string as below, I needed to replace some portion of that without effecting to others.

### Current String

> "http://mydomain.com/app/web/index.php/reqyest/RequestForm/id/661,#SDATERANGE#from#DATE#2015-03-23#DATERANGE#to#DATE#2015-03-26#DATERANGE##DATECLAIMID#1100#DATECLAIMID##SDATERANGE#,#TIMERANGE#fromtime-11:00#TIME#totime-23:00#TIME##TIMECLAIMID#1100#TIMECLAIMID##TIMERANGE#,84.0/0.00/732.9/Overseas//,@1100%22%@#17#Taxi fare & Limousine:123.49:jkta trip-ppit agm taxi.pdf:1100;"

### Extected String

> "http://mydomain.com/reqyest/RequestForm/id/661,#SDATERANGE#from#DATE#2015-03-23#DATERANGE#to#DATE#2015-03-26#DATERANGE##DATECLAIMID#1100#DATECLAIMID##SDATERANGE#,#TIMERANGE#fromtime-11:00#TIME#totime-23:00#TIME##TIMECLAIMID#1100#TIMECLAIMID##TIMERANGE#,84.0/0.00/732.9/Overseas//,@1100%22%@#17#Taxi fare & Limousine:123.49:jkta trip-ppit agm taxi.pdf:1100;"

Below is the query that I'm using.

```
update table_name set table_name.field = replace (field,"/app\/web\/index.php\/","/");
```

I tried suggestions that are available in below without a success.

[mysql: replace \ (backslash) in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059450/mysql-replace-backslash-in-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the '/' with a '\' to let mysql know that it's a character of the field and not a special one.
Try this:

```
update table_name set table_name.field = replace(field,"\/app\/web\/index.php\/","\/")
```

Comment: it Does now have an effect

Answer (score 0):

I got the following result, which is as you expect.
"/" is not a escape character, so no special handling is need.

```
mysql> SELECT REPLACE ( "http://example.com/app/web/index.php/reqyest/RequestForm/id/661,#SDATERANGE#from#DATE#2015-03-23#DATERANGE#to#DATE#2015-03-26#DATERANGE##DATECLAIMID#1100#DATECLAIMID##SDATERANGE#,#TIMERANGE#fromtime-11:00#TIME#totime-23:00#TIME##TIMECLAIMID#1100#TIMECLAIMID##TIMERANGE#,84.0/0.00/732.9/Overseas//,@1100%22%@#17#Taxi fare & Limousine:123.49:jkta trip-ppit agm taxi.pdf:1100;",
    -> "/app/web/index.php/","/");
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REPLACE ( "http://example.com/app/web/index.php/reqyest/RequestForm/id/661,#SDATERANGE#from#DATE#2015-03-23#DATERANGE#to#DATE#2015-03-26#DATERANGE##DATECLAIMID#1100#DATECLAIMID##SDATERANGE#,#TIMERANGE#fromtime-11:00#TIME#totime-23:00#TIME##TIMECLAIMID#110                                                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http://example.com/reqyest/RequestForm/id/661,#SDATERANGE#from#DATE#2015-03-23#DATERANGE#to#DATE#2015-03-26#DATERANGE##DATECLAIMID#1100#DATECLAIMID##SDATERANGE#,#TIMERANGE#fromtime-11:00#TIME#totime-23:00#TIME##TIMECLAIMID#1100#TIMECLAIMID##TIMERANGE#,84.0/0.00/732.9/Overseas//,@1100%22%@#17#Taxi fare & Limousine:123.49:jkta trip-ppit agm taxi.pdf:1100; |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```